# Cannot connect to MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

i am trying to test the connection to my database but i keep getting the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'db'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:798)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3700)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1203)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2572)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1485)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at ConnectingToDB.main(ConnectingToDB.java:18)
```

My code is below. The error occurs on the line 
"conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);"

```
public class ConnectingToDB
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
    Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "steven";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "db"; 
    String password = "db";
    try 
    {
      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
      System.out.println("Connected to the database");
      conn.close();
      System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

}

Comment: make sure your user and password are correct and they have access to the db from local/remote machines

Comment: `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);` - shouldn't there be a `,` instead of `+`?

Comment: Are you sure the password is correct?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius `url+dbName = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/steven` that's a valid url to connect mysql

Comment: Luiggi and Sepala my password is definetly correct as i can use it to access the MySql Command line client.Andrius, it will only allow me to add 3 parameters.Also Luiggi i tried that and it didnt work

Comment: Why've you named your database steven and your username and password db ? Are you sure you haven't got them the wrong way around ?

Comment: have you tried to connect to **steven** database with same user/password using another client like MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Nope i am just trying it out, they are correct

Comment: Ah ye were right. I had the wrong DB username. Should have been "root". Cheers

Answer (score 2):

As you can see that your credentials are processed by MySql however denied, it means the the problem may not be directly related with credentials because if credentials are wrong the error would have been different then denied. When credentials are denied, the problem is mostly related with:

1. Permission issue - Solution >> Grant permission to use "db" from "Localhost"
2. Your connection string looks fine but sometimes string encoding result this error
3. Some installed components are interfering with MySql -> Check the components installation

Try troubleshooting above steps one by one..

Comment: Thank you my problem was a permission issue. My server host blocks all connections other than localhost and I got the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

you should check whether **db@localhost** exist in your mysql. Otherwise create this user profile with necessary privileges.

```
CREATE USER user_specification
    [, user_specification] ...

user_specification:
    user [IDENTIFIED BY [PASSWORD] 'password']
```

For details check [CREATE USER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html)

Answer (score 0):

LOCALHOST and "machine name" aren't the same to MySQL.  I'd check from the command line that you can connect to localhost:

`mysql -hlocalhost -udb -pdb steven`

If it fails, connect and run this with the appropriate permissions:

```
create user db@localhost identified by 'db';
grant select on steven.* to db@localhost;
```